# VBA copy rows that meet criteria to another sheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am new to VBA...I want to copy a row from Sheet2 to Sheet1 if the first cell in this row says X and then do so for all the rows that meet this criteria. I have an error in the If condition...I don't know how to fix it.

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox (LastRow)
    For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Worksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
    ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy _
    Destination:=Hoja1
    End If
    Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: Try [AUTOFILTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Comment: I would if I´d knew programming...I´ve been learning VBA for...two days now :) this is a way I can understand what is the code about...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify workseet. Change line

```
If Worksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
```

to

```
If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
```

**UPD:**

Try to use following code (but it's not the best approach. As @SiddharthRout suggested, consider about using [Autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)):

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("Sheet2")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   MsgBox (LastRow)
   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With 

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("Sheet2")
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 as it answers the question :) However definitely not the best way to copy rows across as it does that in a loop. `Autofilter` is the best thing for this as I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: thanks, but now I have a new error later on in:   ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy _
Destination:=Sheet1 .... it says the object doesn't admit this propriety or method..

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I totally agree with you! Autofilter would be the best in this case.

Comment: @user3187303: you also need to chnage `ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy` to `Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Copy`

Comment: @user3187303, what is the `Hoja1`?

Comment: sorry, it's sheet1, I had to translate from spanish to english because I coudn't find a proper spanish forum for this :)

Comment: it still says error in copy method from range class...                  
    
    Worksheets("Hoja2").Rows(i).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheet1
    End If

Comment: better like this, but assume in Sheet 1 I already have information and I want to paste what I copied just at the end of the Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

After formatting the previous answer to my own code, I have found an efficient way to copy all necessary data if you are attempting to paste the values returned via `AutoFilter` to a separate sheet.

```
With .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    .Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
    .Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").activate
    DestinationRange.PasteSpecial
End With
```

In this block, the `AutoFilter` finds all of the rows that contain the value of `strSearch` and filters out all of the other values. It then copies the cells (using offset in case there is a header), opens the destination sheet and pastes the values to the specified range on the destination sheet.