# How do I loop through a column, if a cell matches some criteria then paste that whole row into another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which selects the value I want however I want to know how I can then copy that row based on finding that value then paste into another worksheet at a specific point e.g. Worksheet 2 E5.

```
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E:E")  
    If cell.Value = "Rob" Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA copy rows that meet criteria to another sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074874/vba-copy-rows-that-meet-criteria-to-another-sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't paste a row into cell E5 for example, because the copied row will be longer than the space you allow to paste into

```
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E:E")  
    If cell.Value = "Rob" Then
        Worksheets(2).Range("E5").EntireRow.Value = cell.EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next
```

But that will keep over riding the same row, better something like

```
i = 1
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E:E")  
    If cell.Value = "Rob" Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value = cell.EntireRow.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Also look into getting the last cell in column E so you're not wasting time iterating all 1 millions rows, like `Sheets(1).Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)`

**EDIT**

As per your comment

```
i = 1
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell.Value = "Rob" Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 5).Value = Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Tim, that is useful. However how can I only copy cells A2-E2 for example if the value was Rob at E2 to a specific point in my 2nd worksheet.

Comment: There seems to be typographical error in your final edit. I feel that the line ~For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)~ should read as ~For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)~

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim.