# Copy rows based on conditions, and paste those rows into different workbooks based on the conditions (EXCEL VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone recommend a good video for me about this Excel VBA problem

I have a Master workbook with a few thousand rows. Based on the value in Column 2, I need to copy each row to one of 10 different workbooks.

So far I have found only this video: http://www.familycomputerclub.com/copy-data-to-another-workbook-based-on-sales-date.html

It has been helpful but it has not enabled me to get all the way there.

Can anyone recommend a good video that will walk through this with me. I am looking for a video so I understand what I am doing, rather than just copying and pasting code.

Thank you!

Here is what I have so far. The issue is that with the below code, for every row that needs to be copy and pasted... the new copy-to workbook opens, saves, and closes. So if there are 30 rows in the Master workbook that meet the criteria to be copied into the copy-to workbook... with each row it is

1. copy row from master workbook
2. open copy-to workbook
3. paste in copy-to workbook
4. save copy-to workbook
5. close copy-to workbook

Code:

```
Sub updateAllWorkbooks()

a = Worksheets("All").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("All").Cells(i, 2).Value = "DENVER" Then

        Worksheets("All").Rows(i).Copy
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="FILE NAME IS PASTED HERE"
        Worksheets("DENVER").Activate
        b = Worksheets("DENVER").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("DENVER").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("All").Activate

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this be a recurring task or something you need to do only once?

Comment: This will be re-occuring. The Master workbook gets updated throughout the day. And at the end of every day the 10 different workbooks will need to be updated based on those master workbook changes. Thank you!

Comment: I commend your desire to find a video that *teaches* you, rather than just giving you code to copy/paste - a great first step!  Unfortunately, this question is a little off-topic for SO.  This site is for programming specific questions ("help me with my code"), where you post some code and what error/issue you're having.  That being said, you will want to search for things like "VBA copy data to separate workbooks", "vba find full row based on match" will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I see. I do have the below code in Excel. This is just to copy rows with one condition into one workbook. (Thought I would start small).

Comment: @ElisaNicole - Oh, great! Please edit your original post to include the code you do have, and any comments (do you get errors, does it work, but unexpected results, etc.)?  (Format the code with the code tags, `{}`).

Comment: In that case this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074874/vba-copy-rows-that-meet-criteria-to-another-sheet

Comment: @BruceWayne I just did thank you. Sorry I didn't realize I couldn't add it all in the comment. First time posting a question on here!

Comment: Thanks @Marcucciboy2 ! I was actually able to execute code for copying and pasting between sheets just fine. I am now trying to rework it (slowly) to copy and paste between workbooks and this is where I am running into challenges.

Comment: Oh okay you’ll possibly want to create workbook objects for each of the 10 that you want to paste to/from and then set those objects using workbooks.open. Then you can just say like `workbookA.sheets("sheet").Rows(...).value = workbookB.sheets("sheet").Rows(...).value`

Comment: I will look into this thank you @Marcucciboy2

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 This worked, thank you!