# Copy entire row based on a cell value and paste in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to:
Copy an entire row from Sheet1 if cell value in the row is for example >3000.
Paste that row in sheet2.

It gets stuck at `EntireRow.EntireRow` while I am trying to copy that entire row to sheet2.

```vb
Sub deviation()

    Dim DataRg As Range
    Dim blankrng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim I As Long

    Q = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    P = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If I = 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange) = 0 Then Q = 0
    End If

    Set DataRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:w185" & P)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) >= "3000" Then
        EntireRow.EntireRow
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Sheet1

```
a  10   100   4000
b  15   102   2900
c  3000 3010  129
```

Expected output, as the value in at least one cell is >3000

```
a  10   100   4000
c  3000 3010  129
```

Comment: "Unable to get it right" is not a helpful description of your problem. Apart from `EntireRow.EntireRow` throwing an error, what else happens?

Comment: Yeah - It gets stuck at this point EntireRow.EntireRow.

Comment: While I am trying to copy that entire row and paste it to sheet2

Comment: `I = 1` will never pass as it's not given a value after declaration. You're not looping through the range either. Check [this documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells).

Comment: Yeah could you pls help me correct it!

Comment: @kalpesh `EntireRow.EntireRow` is just a Range object.  Excel throws an error, because you're not saying what you want to **do** with the object.  It's like if I just said "kalpesh"…  Eventually, you'd ask  "Yes? What do you want?" — that's basically what the error is.  I'd need to give information, such as "kalpesh, drink a glass of water", or `EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Rows(Q+1)`

Comment: Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074942/19353309) about copying the row if a cell meets a criteria. If you'd be using a cell from `For each c in DataRg.Cells` (like in the first link I gave you), you could then use `c.EntireRow.Copy` and then you'd need the destination. Don't forget to have a counter or check each time what the last row in the destination sheet is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should help you achieve your expected outcome:

```
Sub deviation()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet: Set wsCopyFrom = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsPasteTo As Worksheet: Set wsPasteTo = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    'above declare and set the relevant worksheets
    Dim LastRowSheet1 As Long, LastRowSheet2 As Long, counter As Long
    'declare variables to verify last rows in both worksheets

    LastRowSheet1 = wsCopyFrom.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with some data on Column A Sheet1
    NextRowSheet2 = wsPasteTo.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the last row with some data on Column A Sheet2 and add 1
    
    For counter = 1 To LastRowSheet1
    'loop throught Rows 1 to Last on Sheet1
        If wsCopyFrom.Cells(counter, 2).Value >= "3000" Or wsCopyFrom.Cells(counter, 3).Value >= "3000" Or wsCopyFrom.Cells(counter, 4).Value >= "3000" Then
        'Check if any value in Column B, C or D have a value greater or equal to 3000
            wsCopyFrom.Rows(counter).EntireRow.Copy wsPasteTo.Range("A" & NextRowSheet2)
            NextRowSheet2 = NextRowSheet2 + 1
        End If
    Next counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! it seems to be in the direction of what I was looking for . i will take it from here! Thank you

Comment: @kalpesh please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To start, here is your code with comments:

```
Sub deviation()

    Dim DataRg As Range
    Dim blankrng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim I As Long

'You have not Declared Q
    Q = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
'You have not Declared P
    P = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'You never set the value of I, so it is ALWAYS 0...
    If I = 1 Then
'... meaning that this bit will NEVER run
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange) = 0 Then Q = 0
    End If

'Your sample data makes P = 3.  This means you are looking at Range B2:W1853
'Did you mean Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:w" & P) instead?
    Set DataRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:w185" & P)
'You never set this back to True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'I is always 0, so this will throw an error
    If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) >= "3000" Then
'This is an Object.  You Excel/VBA wants to know what you want to DO with the object!
        EntireRow.EntireRow
    End If
    
End Sub
```

So, let's see what might work instead:

```
Option Explicit 'Throw an Error if you forgot to Declare any Variables
Sub deviation()
    Dim wsSrc AS Worksheet, wsDest AS Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Possibly ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(..)
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Or maybe ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(..)
    
    If Application.CountA(wsSrc .Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion) < 1 Then Exit Sub 'If there is no data in the Source Sheet
    
    Dim SourceRow As Range, lOutputRow AS Long
    
    'Find an Empty row in the Destination sheet
    If Application.CountA(wsDest.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion) > 0 Then
        lOutputRow = 1 + wsDest.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'UsedRange can be buggy if you delete rows
        'Using Range.End(..) or Range.CurrentRegion are more reliable
    Else
        lOutputRow = 1 'If there is no data already in the Destination Sheet
    End IF
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For Each SourceRow In wsSrc.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows 'Step through each row, one at a Time
        If Application.CountIf(SourceRow, ">=3000") > 0 Then 'At least 1 cell in the row has a value >= 3000
            SourceRow.Copy Destination:=wsDest.Rows(lOutputRow) 'Copy to Destination Sheet
            lOutputRow = lOutputRow + 1 'Move Output to the next row down
        End If
    Next SourceRow
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Matching Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyMatchingRows()
    
    ' Constants
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMNS As String = "B:W"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const GREATER_THAN_VALUE As Double = 3000
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, scCount As Long

    With sws.UsedRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        Set srg = .EntireRow.Columns(SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMNS) _
            .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
        scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    End With
       
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
       
    Dim surg As Range, sValue As Variant, sr As Long, sc As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            sValue = sData(sr, sc)
            If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                If sValue > GREATER_THAN_VALUE Then
                    If surg Is Nothing Then
                        Set surg = srg.Cells(sr, 1)
                    Else
                        Set surg = Union(surg, srg.Cells(sr, 1))
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next sc
    Next sr
            
    If surg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching rows found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim dcell As Range:
    With dws.UsedRange
        Set dcell = .Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns("A").Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
    
    ' Copy.
    surg.EntireRow.Copy dcell
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Matching rows copied.", vbInformation
     
End Sub
```